# How to translate "to giggle"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How to translate "to giggle" (German: "kichern")?

Logical would be "rideti", but that's already taken for "to smile" and well-established in that meaning.

Google translate gives "subridi" or "subrido" for both English "giggle" and German "kichern". But PIV [defines that](https://vortaro.net/#subridi_kd) as

> Kaŝe ridi

and ReVo [as](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/rid.html#rid.sub0i)

> Kaŝe ridi, subpremi sian ridon

and gives as translation to French

> pouffer, rire dans sa barbe

so this seems closer to "to laugh up one's sleeve" / "sich ins Fäustchen lachen".

In my opinion, while "giggling" / "kichern" can be due to avoiding or trying to hide laughing, but can also happen by itself openly. Is there am Esperanto way to express the kind of giggling that isn't hidden or suppressed laughter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vi povas uzi [`subridi`](https://vortaro.net/#subridi_kd).

La prefikso [`sub-`](https://vortaro.net/#sub_kd) povas rilati kaŝitecon, sed ankaŭ donas ideon pri ne tute plena rido.

> - Nesufiĉecon, neatingon de la normala nivelo
> - Kaŝitecon, sekretecon aŭ hipokritecon de la ago

Ĉi okaze, mi sentas ke la nepleneco venas el la daŭra interrompo de aerfluo, kiu estas ĉefa trajto de "giggle" [en la angla](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giggle).

Comment: Kvankam Z mem uzis la vorton "subridi" en la senco de "kaŝe ridi" laŭ PIV, mi aŭtomate komprenas "subridi" kiel [de] "kichern", [fi] "hihittää", [sv] "fnittra". Por "kaŝe ridi" mi uzus "kaŝridi" aŭ "kaŝe ridi" :-D

Answer (score 3):

[John Wells' dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has this:

> **giggle** (nervoz-e, embaras-e, koket-e) rid-i, -a -o; subrid(aĉ)-i, -o

Maybe *kokete ridi* could be suitable for the example you describe where the laugh is not hidden.